# Best practice for NHibernate Linq Query

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 3 NHibernate entities

```
Division
{
  Id (PK),
  Name
}

District
{
  Id (PK),
  Name
}

Doctor
{
  Id (PK),
  Name,
  Division,
  District
}
```

I want to get *doctors* filtering by the *division* and *district*.

I can write query by two way, say I have a user-selected Division and I want the doctors under this division.

First way:

```
var doctors = doctorRepository
    .FilterBy(x => x.Division.Id == selectedDivision.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Second Way:

```
var doctors = doctorRepository
    .FilterBy(x => x.Division == selectedDivision)
    .ToList();
```

My First question is, which is the best way considering the performance?

I checked the sql profiler for both queries. 
For first query, the generated sql contains a left outer join with division table. I can't understand why it needs to join with Division table as the DivisionId reside in the Doctor table. Will this extra join reduce the performance?

My Second question: if I want to query from the doctor repository using Division and District and both division and district can be null sometimes, in this case how should I write this query in NHibernate Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For first query, the generated sql contains a left outer join with division table. I can't understand why it needs to join with Division table as the DivisionId reside in the Doctor table. Will this extra join reduce the performance?

It may not strictly need to, probably it's just that this detail isn't optimized by the NHibernate Linq provider. Unless your database engine realizes that it can be optimized away (look at the execution plan for the SQL), it will affect performance. How much is impossible to tell in the general case.

> My Second question: if I want to query from the doctor repository using Division and District and both division and district can be null sometimes, in this case how should I write this query in NHibernate Linq?

Consider a query such as:

```
var doctors = doctorRepository
    .FilterBy(x => x.Division.Id == selectedDivision.Id)
    .ToList();
```

When executed by Linq2NH it will be converted to SQL. If x.Division is NULL nothing bad will happen, because the expression will never be dereferenced in .NET. I'm uncertain if NHibernate will try to dereference selectedDivision (causing NRE) or if it's smart enough to convert `selectedDivision.Id` into NULL if `selectedDivision`is NULL. Try it! Otherwise, a safer way is to write:

```
int? divId = selectedDivision != null ? selectedDivision.Id : (int?)null;
var doctors = doctorRepository
    .FilterBy(x => x.Division.Id == divId)
    .ToList();
```

NHibernate is smart enough to generate IS NULL in the SQL if divId happens to be null.

### Null as indication to avoid filter

I typically use a pattern such as:

```
var queryable = GetMyBaseQueryable<Doctor>();

if (divisionFilter != null)
    queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Division.Id == divisionFilter.Id)

if (districtIdFilter != null)    // districtIdFilter is some collection
    queryable = queryable.Where(x => districtIdFilter.Contains(x.District.Id))

var result = queryable.ToList();
```

Comment: By the way, regarding my second question, actually i want to make the null object as optional. actually, any of Division or District null means user dont want to filter the doctors with it. it doesn't mean that division or district id will be null for the doctors. in this case, if the value is null for division or district, i dont want to include this clause to the query.  which will be the best and easy way for it as i have many other reference objects for a doctor to be filtered?

Comment: @HabiburRahmanShipon I've added an example of optional filters.

Comment: The other thing that can happen is that your Division object can change from when selectedDivision is initialized and when the query happens confusing the nhibernate proxies causing the query to fail.  Typically the best thing to do is to reference everything by Id unless you have a specific need to do otherwise.(Also, passing an ID around uses a lot less resources when passing the whole object.  This becomes important in web applications.)